# Giving 775 permissions to all files in an unix system breaks it, why?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

After a failing a command on my Ubuntu virtual machine on Azure and adding a deadly space

```
 sudo chmod -R 775 / ps_democqrshooksusage/
```

I ended up setting (accidentally) every single file in the system with the permissions 775.

After that I could not SSH to my VM anymore (but the Azure Shell kept working), and I noticed I could not use `sudo` anymore as well.

From what I understand, permissions 775 means that the owner and the group of the owner can do whatever they want and the others can only read and execute the file.

So why did this break some key functionnalities ?

Comment: Hello @PiyushBaderia isn't it chown which changes the owner of the file ?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider indeed thanks for the link. We can close as duplicate